# JRuby/Rails rufus-scheduler stops working after a heap-space in threadsafe mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, rufus-scheduler

A JRuby/Rails application with a rufus-scheduler job that runs daily. However, when the application runs into a Java Heap Space (Tomcat) the job stops running silently.

This apparently occurs only in Threadsafe mode.

Abstracted `config/initializer/update_scheduler.rb`

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

#Runs everyday at 7:30 AM - expected after all ETL/MV refreshes are executed
scheduler.cron("30 7 * * *", :tags => 'auto_update') do
  begin
    # do stuff
    Rails.logger.info "log info and duration"
  rescue Exception => s_e
    Rails.logger.error "Scheduler Failed"
  end
  Rails.logger.flush
end

class << scheduler
  def lwarn (&block)
    Rails.logger.error("Scheduler Error: " + block.call)
  end
end

MyApp::Application.config.scheduler = scheduler
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?  I'm getting a thrift exception *only* when I turn on config.threadsafe! in my Rails 3.2 app:  `Thrift::ProtocolException (No version identifier, old protocol client?)`  This Rails 3.2.13 app is running on JRuby and Puma.  Thanks for any pointers on how to debug why turning ON threadsafe! causes problems...